# Uploaded images not showing, wrong path

Tags: django, upload, path

I've got a problem with displaying images that were uploaded from admin panel. Django renders wrong path, probably due to my configuration mistake somewhere...

This is my model definition:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    """News article, displayed on homepage to attract users"""
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = HTMLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'articles/', null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is url configuration:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# some stuff
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

the view:

```
def slider(request):
    context = Context ({ 'articles': Article.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5] })
    return render(request, 'articles/slider.html', context)
```

and the template:

```
{% for article in articles %}
  <img src="{{ article.image.url }}" alt="" />
```

I would expect django to render `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/articles/slide-02.jpg` but now it renders `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/slide-02.jpg`. I've defined the `upload_to=articles/` in the model class. So why does the `article.image.url` attribute return a path without this significant directory?

---

edit: I've got something wrong with my model. It doesn't recognize the **upload_to** directory:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from articles.models import Article
>>> Article.objects.all()
[<Article: Blackened Recordings Launches>, <Article: The Rockin' Return of Deep Purple>, <Article: See Emily Day 20th April>, <Article: Celebration Day Premieres In Four Countries Announced>, <Article: Waging heavy innovation>, <Article: Rush to play festival D'Ete, Quebec City>]
>>> Article.objects.all().get(pk=1)
<Article: Blackened Recordings Launches>
>>> Article.objects.all().get(pk=1).image
<ImageFieldFile: slide-03.jpg>
>>> Article.objects.all().get(pk=1).image.path
u'/var/www/django/djninja/djninja/media/slide-03.jpg'
>>> Article.objects.all().get(pk=1).image.url
'/media/slide-03.jpg'
```

Again, it should be `media/articles/slide-03.jpg` instead of `media/slide-03.jpg`. So I guess all routing/template is ok, something's wrong with the model.

Comment: It looks ok to me. Perhaps the image was uploaded before you added the `upload_to=articles`? Or you forgot to hit save in your editor after adding that? (Sorry, have to ask).

Comment: all records are loaded with fixtures/syncdb, so I guess it should work ok.

Comment: try `/media/{{ article.image }}/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above solution is perfectly ok. My problem was the improperly configured fixtures written in JSON and loaded into the database. I thought that in you pass `articles` directory as the `upload_to` kwarg, it'll be dynamically loaded. **It's not**. It is used only during saving the image and is ignored during loading the image from the database. Thus, if I had

```
"image":"slide.jpg"
```

I changed it to:

```
"image":"articles/slide.jpg"
```

And it worked. In fact, it worked all the time, but I miss a note on that in django official docs.

Answer (score 2):

In **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext
def slider(request):
    articles = Article.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    return render_to_response('articles/slider.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request)
```

In **slider.html**:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.image.url }}" alt="" />
{% endfor %}
```

In **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Try using the above given codes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use a upload method :

```
def upload_path(self, filename):
    return 'media/articles/%s' % filename

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Comment: I've tried it and nothing changed, since - somehow - `upload_to` is being ignored :/. I looked into django source code and I've found that the both `FileField` and `ImageField` use the `Storage` mechanism. Maybe there's a convention of what value should be passed to `upload_to` kwarg? A convention I don't follow - and this is the cause?

Comment: by the way, if your solution worked, I'd end up with `/media/media/articles/file.jpg` path in the template, since `storage.url`/`storage.path` return `/media/` as it is configured in `settings.py`.