# Django Uploaded images not displayed in development

Tags: django, django-models

I have defined a model with a 'pic' image field:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    teaser = models.TextField('teaser', blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/', default = 'pic_folder/None/default.jpg')
    created=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100,  unique=True, blank=True)
```

And here is the upload form:

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):       

    class Meta:
            model= Photo
            fields = ( 'title', 'pic','body', 'categories')
```

Wich post to this view:

```
@staff_member_required
def add_photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.info(request, "photo was added") 
            return render(request, 'home.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'form not valid')
            return render(request, 'home.html')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PhotoForm()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'photo/add_photo.html', args)
```

The problem is that while photo objects are being saved and the file uploaded but the images are not displayed.

```
  <div class="photo_body"><img src="pic_folder/someimage.jpg" ></div>
```

I also set

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/my_project/pic_folder'
```

and run manage.py collectstatic, but they did not solve the problem.

I really got confused about this. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: problem solved using this tips: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15542779/517235

Answer (score 10):

First of all make a folder called `media` in your project's directory.

Django will store all your uploaded images inside `media/pic_folder/` automatically.

In your `settings.py` file, add this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/path_to/media/' # write the path to the media folder you just created.
```

In your `urls.py` file, add the following lines at the top:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

**and add the following line at the end:**

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**something like below:**

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # Your urls here 

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And, finally, in your `templates`:

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}pic_folder/someimage.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was having trouble with displaying the user-uploaded files, and I had followed all the steps including updating the urls.py file with `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`, but nothing seemed to work.

So I figured this out eventually while reading the docs. I was adding the static(setting.MEDIA_URL ...) line in the urls.py file of my app, but it is actually supposed to be done in the ROOT_URL_CONF urls.py file which is in the same directory as settings.py.