# Django Uploaded images not displayed in production

Tags: django, ubuntu, production

I am aware of this question: [Django Uploaded images not displayed in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417146/django-uploaded-images-not-displayed-in-development) , I have done everything that it is described, but still can't find a solution. I also have used for reference this: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/) and [Uploaded Files and Uploaded Handlers - Django documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/), however, none of them solved my problem.

I have deployed a Django App on a Ubuntu server for the first time using Nginx and gunicorn.
Before deployment, I used port 8000 to test if everything runs as it is supposed to and all was fine. Since I allowed 'Nginx Full' my database images are not showing up.

This is my django project structure:

[image: project structure]

My virtual environment folder and my main project folder are both in the same directory. I have separated them.

```py
# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    project_link = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

I have set up my settings.py to :

```py
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/')
```

My view gets all the project object from a database and passes those to the template. The template renders successfully all other information related to project model except the image field . In my template I do:

```html
 <div class="row text-center mx-auto">

        {% for project in projects %}
        {% if forloop.counter|mod:2 == 0 %}
        <div class="col projects pb-3 pt-3 mb-3 ml-2">
          {% else %}
          <div class="col projects pb-3 pt-3 mb-3 mr-2">
            {% endif %}

            <img class="card-img-top pt-2 pl-2 pr-2" src="{{ project.project_image.url}}"
              alt="Image could not be found :(" style="height:120px; width:166px !important;" /><br>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-title ">{{ project.project_name }}</h3>
              <p class="card-text dates">{{ project.project_description}}</p>
              <a href="{{ project.project_link }}" class="btn btn-dark" target="_blank">Link</a>

            </div>
          </div>

          {% if forloop.counter|mod:2 == 0 %}
          <div class="w-100"></div>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor%}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Uploading the images works, it sends them in the project's media directory, the problem is that they are not showing up, the alt="" is activated.

My main urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
     path('', include('project.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The gunicorn system file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myusername
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myusername/myproject
ExecStart=/home/myusername/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myusername/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx setup:

```
  server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <my IP> ;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/myusername/myproject;
        }
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myusername/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: When inspecting the image element of the webpage the source of the image it is "/media/imageNmae.png".
Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The solution has been found, the Nginx was not serving the media as Daniel suggested. There is some uWSGI documentation which is worth reading to avoid further similar problems  [Documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

Comment: Could you share the rendered url of the media resource? I believe you could get it on your image src attribute when you inspect the image element.

Comment: It's "/media/imageName.png"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Nginx is not serving the `MEDIA_URL` i.e. `/media/`. You need an Nginx configuration section like you have for `/static/`

```
  server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <my IP> ;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/myusername/myproject;
        }
        location /media/ {
            root /home/myusername/myproject;
        }
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myusername/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run this command :
`python manage.py collectstatic` from the shell of your platform
if you are using heroku here is the command

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```